# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter repeating positions

Tags: android, contacts, simplecursoradapter

I made a custom CursorAdapter for showing the contact photo, name and id in one row.

I´ve overwritten the getView() Method, and so on and everything works. My Problem is now, that the adapter fills my list with contacts 1-8 and repeats it. -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 . This is the result of getting only the positions of 1 to 8 but I don´t understand why, because this is the part of the CursorAdapter which is in the parent class and should work.

Changeing my CustomAdapter to the normal SimpleCursorAdapter shows all contacts in the right form.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater vi;

    View v;

    CheckBox box;
    v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item_layout, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactImage);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);

        String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        tv.setText(position+" "+id+" "
                + cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        String photoID = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));

        if (photoID != null) {
            Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    Long.parseLong(photoID));
            image.setImageURI(photoUri);

        }
        box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        box.setTag(id);
        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }
    return v;
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the same views without putting the correct information on them. You may take a look into this tutorial of the adapter-viewholder pattern. You would end up with an efficient and fast adapter, with correct data.

http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Hope that helps :D

Comment: I think the viewholder pattern has nothing to do with my problem, that the position count only reaches from 1 to 8, even if I have hundrets of contacts the cursor is pointing at

Comment: but you're reusing the same view if it's not null. I bet when your app starts you can see only 8 contacts. When the adapter is called again when you scroll, the convertview is an old row that has disappeared by the top, and you only check if it's not null and then return it. Trust me and try to implement the view holder pattern :)

Comment: I have never used it before an never got any problems, but I will implement it anyway :D